# Rotate the object in the direction of its movement

Tags: javascript, three.js

For example, i pressed button "W" and object should turn to side move

[image]

```
if (keyBoard[87]) {
    camera.position.x -= Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.x -= Math.PI / 10;
}

if (keyBoard[83]) {
    camera.position.x += Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.x += Math.PI / 10;
}

if (keyBoard[65]) {
    camera.position.z += Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.z += Math.PI / 10;
}

if (keyBoard[68]) {
    camera.position.z -= Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.z -= Math.PI / 10;
}
```

My simple implementation of move

Comment: `should turn to side move` . I dont think I understand what you want.  Would you please edit your question and write what you are looking to see?

Comment: @petey i guess yes)) so when i pressed "W" i want to see this result: joxi.ru/Q2KeqOjC4xjORr and when i pressed "S": joxi.ru/52aneoJC47OlqA

Comment: _"should turn"_ Immediately or rotate at some speed?

Comment: @prisoner849 maybe at some speed.

coz i found method how to rotate immediately 
bulba.rotation.y = (Math.cos(bulba.position.y) * Math.PI / 2) * -1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very rough concept, using Tween.js:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 5);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var boxGeom = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 3);
boxGeom.translate(0, 0, 2.5);
var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
box.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.5;
scene.add(box);

window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

function onKeyDown(event) {

  if (![65, 68, 83, 87].includes(event.keyCode)) return;

  var angleTo = 0;
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 87:
      angleTo = Math.PI;
      break;
    case 65:
      angleTo = Math.PI * -0.5;
      break;
    case 83:
      angleTo = 0;
      break;
    case 68:
      angleTo = Math.PI * 0.5;
      break;
  }

  startTween(angleTo);

}

function startTween(angleTo) {
  let tween = new TWEEN.Tween(box.rotation).to({
    y: angleTo
  }, 250).onStart(() => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
  }).onComplete(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false)
  });
  tween.start();
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  TWEEN.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.min.js"></script>
```